# Nginx reverse proxy map to multiple frontend & backend

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have a angular frontend and a node.js backend, which I want to deploy for clients in different countries. We need for every country one frontend & backend container. So the idea is that nginx should redirect to the correct container inside the docker compose environment based on the path:

example.com/us/frontend -> us frontend container

example.com/us/backend -> us backend container

example.com/fr/frontend -> fr frontend container

example.com/fr/backend -> fr backend container
...

I've implemented so far:

*docker-compose.yml*

```
version: "3"
services:
  test-proxy:
    container_name: test-proxy
    image: nginx:latest
    depends_on:
      - example-frontend-us # References the service name.
    volumes:
      - ./config/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./content:/usr/share/nginx/html
    ports:
      - 80:80 # Publishs only port 80 outside of docker compose context.

  example-frontend-us:
    container_name: example-frontend-us
    image: angular-frontend
    ports:
      - 8081:80
```

*nginx.conf:*

```
 http {
    server {

        listen 80;
        server_name localhost 127.0.0.1;

        location = / {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            try_files $uri /index.html;
        }
        

        location /us/frontend {
            proxy_pass          http:/example-frontend-us:8081;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        }
    }
}
```

If I open the browser on localhost/us/frontend I get a *502 Bad Gateway* response

If I open the browser on localhost:8081 the frontend is working.

What is wrong here? How can I achieve that nginx is routing to the correct containers?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the virtual network created by docker compose, you use the internal port numbers. So

```
proxy_pass          http:/example-frontend-us:8081;
```

should be

```
proxy_pass          http://example-frontend-us:80;
```

(you're also missing a forward slash in http://)

Finally, you don't need to map the port on example-frontend-us unless you want to be able to reach it directly and bypass nginx.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So I can just remove the -ports flag from docker-compose and pass http://example-frontend-us to proxy_pass? If I'm doing this, I get a 404 response.

Comment: Yes, that should work. One thing: Does your example-frontend-us respond to `/us/frontend` or to `/`? If it's the latter, you need to have a `rewrite` statement to strip the `/us/frontend` bit from the request.

Comment: On / only the nginx default html is responding. On /us/frontend I got a 404 message. But I found a problem: I changed http:/example-frontend-us to http:/example-frontend-us/ and now I get a white page instead of 404. It seems that I get a response. Not sure why the angular frontend is not loading.

Comment: In the console I get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Comment: Which console? The browser console? You could try using `curl` to get a more 'raw' view on what the app is returning.

Comment: Yes, the browser console.

Comment: With curl the app is returning <html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.21.1</center>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Then there should be a URL in the returned headers that tells you where it's moved. The browser will follow that link automatically, so it could be that URL that's giving you weird HTML. You can use the `-I` option on curl to only see the returned headers.

Comment: Response with -I option: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx/1.21.1
Date: Mon, 09 Aug 2021 13:44:31 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 153
Connection: keep-alive

Comment: I think there is a problem with the location. It seems that the root folder is not found. Maybe I have to configure something in the frontend, not sure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235787/discussion-between-wyndham007-and-hans-kilian).